# VNext build system: don't trigger the build if code is not changed

Tags: msbuild, vnext

In XAML build system in VS2012, there is an check box option "Build even if nothing has changed since the previous build", when Schedule option is selected.

This is missing in VNext build and the problem is that nightly build is fired even if no code was committed during the day. In my case it takes two hours to build with complete test suite.

Is there an easy workaround or plug in to achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In TFS VNext build system Microsoft removed this option.

I would use an alternative instance of a workaround, you can create a build definition with a CI-trigger.
Another benefits of this practice is you get fast feedback if a change can not be integrated in the code base.

In this case you maybe need more than one build agent to run parallel builds in the case of parallel check-ins.

> There is a feature request for it. But I think MS will not realize this request
>
> https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-2015/suggestions/16300498-add-build-event-if-nothing-has-changed-since-prev